# Error installing package using npm instead of yarn

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package, yarnpkg

I have created git repository which will be used as npm package in other project. Lets say that sharable repository name is **genesis-service-broker**.

I am using this shareable repository inside one of the service(**activation** service). In this project, I am installing package using **yarn**. Its running perfectly fine here.

```
    "dependencies": {
        ...
        "genesis-service-broker": "git+https://${key}:x-oauth-basic@git.my_project.com/${user}/genesis-service-broker.git#create_service_broker_for_genesis",
        ...
    }
```

When I am trying to use **genesis-service-broker** package inside onother service(**partner** service) its not able to install the dependencies. In this project, I am installing dependencies using **npm**. If I install dependencies using **yarn** its working perfectly fine.

I am not getting any errors in **npm install** command. I am just not able to find **genesis-service-broker** folder inside **node_modules**, when I am installing dependencies using **npm**.

**package.json** file inside **genesis-service-broker** repository. (for reference purposes)

```
{
  "name": "service-broker",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git@git.my_project.com:amol.barewar/service-broker.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "config": "^3.2.5",
    "form-data": "^3.0.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "uuid": "^3.4.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a difference in behaviour here, between `yarn` and `npm`

`yarn add` retains the name of the **git** project in dependencies, and creates a folder with the same name in node_modules.

So, `yarn add git+https://${key}:x-oauth-basic@git.my_project.com/${user}/genesis-service-broker.git#create_service_broker_for_genesis` will lead to a module getting installed as **node_modules/genesis-service-broker**

On the other side, `npm install` gets the name from the `name` property in package.json; and it will lead to module getting added as **node_modules/service-broker** in your case... and also the dependencies map will be like

```
"dependencies": {
   ...
   "service-broker": "git+https://${key}:x-oauth-basic@git.my_project.com/${user}/genesis-service-broker.git#create_service_broker_for_genesis",
   ...
}
```

Because of this difference, the `requires(...)` might fail.

As, in this case, with **yarn** that module will be available through -

```
require('genesis-service-broker')
```

And for **npm** through -

```
require('service-broker')
```

So, all in all, it will help to keep the **name** property in package.json same as the project name.